# Retrieve has_many association as hash by property of child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is it possible to retrieve the child elements in a `has_many` association into a hash based on one of their properties?

For example, imagine a menu that has a single dish for each day:

```
class Menu
  has_many :dishes
end
```

and

```
class Dish
  belongs_to :menu
end
```

`Dish` has a key, `day`, which is one of either `monday`, `tuesday` etc. Is there some way to set up the `has_many` association such that `Menu.dishes` returns a hash similar to `{:monday => 'spaghetti', :tuesday => 'tofu', ... }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Something like this should suffice (assuming e.g. "spaghetti" is stored in a column called `food`).

```
class Dish
  belongs_to :menu

  scope :by_day { select [ :day, :food ] }

  def self.by_day_hash
    by_day.all.reduce({}) {|hsh,dish| hsh[dish.day] = dish.food; hsh }
  end
end

class Menu
  has_many :dishes

  def dishes_by_day
    dishes.by_day_hash
  end
end

# Usage
m = Menu.where( ... )
m.dishes_by_day #=> { "monday" => "Spaghetti", "tuesday" => "Tofu" }
```

So what's happening here is that in `Dish` the `by_day` scope returns only two columns, `day` and `food`. It still, however, returns `Dish` objects rather than a Hash (because that's what scopes do), so we define a class method, `by_day_hash` which takes that result and turns it into a Hash.

Then in `Menu` we define `dishes_by_day` which just calls the method we made above on the association. You could just call this `dishes` but I think it's better to keep that name for the original association since you might want to use it for other things later on.

Incidentally *(**optional** stuff below, skip for now if your eyes have glazed over)*, I might define `by_day_hash` like this instead:

```
class Dish
  belongs_to :menu

  scope :by_day { select [ :day, :hash ] }

  def to_s
    food
  end

  def by_day_hash
    hsh = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
    by_day.reduce(hsh) {|hsh, dish| hsh[dish.day] = dish }
  end
end

# Usage
m = Menu.where( ... )
m.dishes_by_day #=> { "monday" => #<Dish food: "Spaghetti", ...>, "tuesday" => #<Dish food: "Tofu", ...>, ... }
```

...This way you still get the full `Dish` object when you call e.g. `by_day_hash["monday"]` but the `to_s` method means you can just drop it into a view like `<%= @menu.dishes_by_day["monday"] %>` and get "Spaghetti" instead of `#<Dish day: "monday", food: "Spaghetti">`.

Finally, you might also notice I used `HashWithIndifferentAccess.new` instead of `{}` (Hash). HashWithIndifferentAccess is a class provided (and used everywhere) by Rails that is identical to Hash but lets you do either e.g. `some_hash["monday"]` or `some_hash[:monday]` and get the same result. Totally optional but very handy.

Comment: Nice one, thanks! Still getting my head around all the cool little things you can do with Ruby and with Rails.

Comment: Glad I could help, @Russell. The ActiveRecord Guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) is a really useful one that it doesn't hurt to read in its entirety every week or two. ;) P.S. I noticed I left out the `:` in `scope :by_day`. You'll want to mind that!

Comment: `by_day_hash` should be returning `hsh` for this to work as intended.

Comment: Good catch, pgb. I wasn't returning `hsh` in the `reduce` block which was gumming up the works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice way to do it in modern ActiveRecords and Rubys:

```
# In class Menu
def foods_by_day
  Hash[ dishes.pluck(:day, :food) ]
end
```

`dishes.pluck(:day, :food)` returns an array like `[ ['monday', 'spaghetti'], ['tuesday', 'tofu], ... ]`; `Hash[]` converts that array-of-arrays into a hash.